# Why Twig tags are not interpreted?

Tags: php, html, css, twig, silex

I am currently setting the standards a PHP project that was coded framework and without the former (JS / SQL / PHP in views).
So I refactored a good big portion and I am putting in place the framework and Silex Twig template engine for views.
My problem is that Twig tags are not executed (they are quoted):
[Source code HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxUF2.png)

What you see:
[Error Twig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5SQM.png)

Here's the code of my Twig page in question, there must have syntax errors I think:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse templatemo-sidebar"></br>
    <ul class="templatemo-sidebar-menu" id="listMenu">
        <li>
            <form class="navbar-form">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="templatemo_search_box" placeholder="Rechercher..." onkeyup="refreshSearch()">
                <span class="btn btn-default" onclick="searchItem(templatemo_search_box.value)"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
            </form>
            <script src="../../web/js/script_inc_menubase.js"></script>
        </li>
        <!-- HOME -->
        <li class="active"><a href="../../views/app_main/aff_index.php"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>

        {% include '../../src/ressources/DataModule/utilsdb.php' %}

        {% set login = mySession->getValue('login') %}
        {% include '../../src/include/inc_requeteMenuBase.php' %}

        <!-- HOME -->

        {% if SearchMenu('Administration', TabMenu) == true %}
            {% set TabURL = RecupURL(login, GetIndexM('Administration')) %}
            {% set TabPage = RecupNom(login, GetIndexM('Administration')) %}

            <!-- ADMINISTRATION -->
            <li class="sub">
                <a href="javascript:">
                    <i class="fa fa-users"></i> Administration <div class="pull-right"><span class="caret"></span></div>
                </a>
                <ul class="templatemo-submenu">
                    {% for i in i<count(TabURL) %}
                        <li><a  href='../../{{ TabURL[i] }}'> {{ TabPage[i] }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}

                </ul>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

        <!-- RAPPORTS -->
        {% if SearchMenu('Rapport', TabMenu) == true %}
            {% set TabURL = RecupURL(login, GetIndexM('Rapport') %}
            {% set TabPage = RecupNom(login, GetIndexM('Rapport') %}

            <li class="sub">
                <a href="javascript:">
                    <i class="fa fa-table"></i> Rapports <div class="pull-right"><span class="caret"></span></div>
                </a>
                <ul class="templatemo-submenu">
                    {% for i in i<count(TabURL) %}
                        <li><a  href='../../{{ TabURL[i] }}'> {{ TabPage[i] }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

        <!-- OUTILS -->
        {% if SearchMenu('Outils', TabMenu) == true %}
            {% set TabURL = RecupURL(login, GetIndexM('Outils') %}
            {% set TabPage = RecupNom(login, GetIndexM('Outils') %}

            <li class="sub">
                <a href="javascript:">
                    <i class="fa fa-flash"></i> Outils <div class="pull-right"><span class="caret"></span></div>
                </a>
                <ul class="templatemo-submenu">
                    {% for i in i<count(TabURL) %}
                        <li><a href='../../{{ TabURL[i] }}'> {{ TabPage[i] }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

        <!-- AUDITS (non utilisé pour le moment) -->
        {% if SearchMenu('Audits', TabMenu) == true %}
            {% set TabURL = RecupURL(login, GetIndexM('Audits') %}
            {% set TabPage = RecupNom(login, GetIndexM('Audits') %}
            <li class="sub">
                <a href="javascript:">
                    <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Audits <div class="pull-right"><span class="caret"></span></div>
                </a>
                <ul class="templatemo-submenu">
                    {% for i in i<count(TabURL) %}
                        <li><a href='../../{{ TabURL[i] }}'> {{ TabPage[i] }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </li>
        {% endif %}

        <!-- GESTION DONNES -->
        {% if SearchMenu('Gestion Données', TabMenu) == true %}
            {% set TabURL = RecupURL(login, GetIndexM('Gestion Données') %}
            {% set TabPage = RecupNom(login, GetIndexM('Gestion Données') %}

            <li class="sub">
                <a href="javascript:">
                    <i class="fa fa-database"></i> Gestion Données <div class="pull-right"><span class="caret"></span></div>
                </a>
                <ul class="templatemo-submenu">
                    {% for i in i<count(TabURL) %}
                        <li><a href='../../{{ TabURL[i] }}'> {{ TabPage[i] }} </a></li>
                    {% endfor %}

                </ul>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->

</html>
```

Comment: You have tagged this with Symfony2 - can we see the (PHP) controller that is loading this file? I would expect to see something like `return $this->render('template.html.twig');`

Comment: You should name your file `.twig` not `.php`

Answer (score 0):

Please, add php code, where you define Twig; It seems that you set wrong path for inlcudes;

Check where you define template folder. And set path in template relative to you template path.

```
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__.'/v2/Templates');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed I forget to tell where my views directory Twig.